# How can I check the size of a folder from the Windows command line?

Tags: windows, command-line

I want to use the Windows command line to calculate the size of all the files in a folder and subfolder. I would normally do this by right-clicking on the folder and clicking "Properties" but I want to be able to do it on the command line.

Which command can I use?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You will want to use `dir /a/s` so that it includes every file, including system and hidden files.  This will give you the total size you desire.

Comment: Show me how the output of your command gives me the total size of the directory.  Edit your answer to include it.  I'll delete my comments and reverse my down vote.

Comment: @user1167442 You clearly haven't tried it. The output includes the exact same size that explorer properties gives you.

Comment: @DavidPostill - you are correct.  I am hang-doggedly ashamed.  I will reverse the downvote.  That said, I'm still not too keen on this solution - I'd prefer something a bit faster that doesn't require outputting all the other stuff, but it does work.  I have erred.  - Ahh nuts - it won;t let me reverse my downvote.  As soon as I get the reputation to do so, I will reverse it.

Comment: @user1167442 Apology accepted.  If you press the up arrow for the answer, it reverses the downvote. ;)

Comment: - it won't reverse it for me.  I think it must be too soon or require more reputation before it will let me reverse it.

Comment: It worked - downvote removed -)

Comment: @user1167442 Thanks. I had a hunch that would allow it to work. :)

Comment: thanks for this +. Is there a way to list in descending size order?

Comment: @QHarr Yes, go ahead and post a question and I'll write up an answer for you.  That way, it will help everyone by being searchable for all to find.

Comment: `/a` causes the `dir` command to [show all files and folders](https://superuser.com/questions/277379/windows-command-line-command-to-list-hidden-folders/1433463#1433463). See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir

Comment: For me, this answer doesn't really answer the question - I have a large directory and want to know the TOTAL size - this command prints the size of each file - the total may be there too but it is not findable in the long list.

Answer (score 27):

You can use PowerShell!

```
$totalsize = [long]0
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | % {$totalsize += $_.Length}
$totalsize
```

This recurses through the entire current directory (ignoring directories that can't be entered) and sums up the sizes of each file. Then it prints the total size in bytes.

Compacted one-liner:

```
$totalsize=[long]0;gci -File -r -fo -ea Silent|%{$totalsize+=$_.Length};$totalsize
```

On my machine, this seems slightly faster than a `dir /s /a`, since it doesn't print each object's information to the screen.

To run it from a normal command prompt:

```
powershell -command "$totalsize=[long]0;gci -File -r -fo -ea Silent|%{$totalsize+=$_.Length};$totalsize"
```

Comment: I wish I spent more time with powershell.  I just never like using it for some reason - even though it is super useful for lots of stuff

Comment: Great solution - really quick too!

Comment: I get `Get-ChildItem : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'File'`

Comment: @golimar What Windows or PowerShell version do you have? This works on PowerShell 5.1 (standard for Windows 10) and PowerShell 7, but possibly not on older versions that come with older versions of Windows. I think you could instead remove the `-File` parameter and instead pipe through `? { $_ -is [System.IO.FileInfo] }` before piping into the size accumulator.

Comment: Thanks. It's PS 2.0 on Win7, and it works with that modification

Answer (score 12):

<s>There is no such command built into DOS or Windows Command Line.</s> On Linux, there’s the [`du`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/du) (**D**isk **U**sage) command.

Microsoft’s Sysinternals line of tools has a tool that is roughly equivalent to `du` on Linux. [It’s also called `du`.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896651.aspx) ;)

Comment: `du -sh <directory>` is my go to on Linux (or windows w/ du via git) to show a human readable summary of the directory size.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed. As discs get bigger it takes longer and longer to right-click-properties to get file sizes and the result can't be selected and copied into calc to ensure splitting over multiple external discs has written *every* file in the source folder. I've put that at the end of a robocopy batch piped to a text file then when the batch ends I've got a total file/folder/size metric that can be copy/pasted into calc to ensure the files and bytes are the same as the source.

Answer (score 4):

You can still use the command line utility `diruse.exe` from the Windows 2000 Resource Kit available here:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927229

It works on Windows 8.1 without any problems.

Comment: Nice find, could you possibly add in an example of usage?

Answer (score 2):

`dir /s` Will list the sizes of all the files and the files in all subfolders

Comment: I suggest running `dir /s /A:-D /d` or `dir /s /A:-D` for a cleaner/clearer view. You can copy cmd.exe's output to something that can highlight the text "File(s)            ### bytes" such as vim, gvim, or editpad.org.

Answer (score 2):

The folder size can be calculated with following batch script:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set size=0
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('dir /s /a /b %1') do set /a size+=%%~zx
echo.!size!

endlocal
```

Comment: How to run this on Windows 7?

Comment: this won't work if the total size is over 2GB due to the limit of arithmetic in cmd

Comment: ...which these days is a pretty serious limitation!

Answer (score 2):

I realize this question asked for file size analysis using `CMD line`.  But if you are open to using `PowerQuery (Excel add-in, versions 2010+)` then you can create some pretty compelling file size analysis.

The script below can be pasted into a Blank Query; The only thing you'll need to do is add a parameter named "paramRootFolderSearch" then add your value, such as "C:\Users\bl0040\Dropbox\".  I used this as a guide: [MSSQLTips: Retrieve file sizes from the file system using Power Query](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4022/retrieve-file-sizes-from-the-file-system-using-power-query/).

This query provided the data for me to create a pivot table (`[Folder Root]> [Folder Parent (1-2)], [Name]`), and I was able to identify a few files that I could deleted which cleared up a lot of space in my directory.

**Here is the M script for PowerQuery**:

```
let
// Parmameters:
    valueRootFolderSearch = paramRootFolderSearch,
    lenRootFolderSearch = Text.Length(paramRootFolderSearch),
//

    Source = Folder.Files(paramRootFolderSearch),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(
Table.SelectColumns(Source,{"Name", "Folder Path", "Attributes"})
,{{"Folder Path", "Folder Path Full"}}),
    #"Expanded Attributes" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "Attributes", {"Content Type", "Kind", "Size"}, {"Content Type", "Kind", "Size"}),
    #"fx_Size(KB)" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Attributes", "Size(KB)", each [Size]/1024),
    #"fx_Size(MB)" = Table.AddColumn(#"fx_Size(KB)", "Size(MB)", each [Size]/1048576),
    #"fx_Size(GB)" = Table.AddColumn(#"fx_Size(MB)", "Size(GB)", each [Size]/1073741824),
    fx_FolderRoot = Table.AddColumn(#"fx_Size(GB)", "Folder Root", each valueRootFolderSearch),
    helper_LenFolderPathFull = Table.AddColumn(fx_FolderRoot, "LenFolderPathFull", each Text.Length([Folder Path Full])),
    fx_FolderDepth = Table.AddColumn(helper_LenFolderPathFull, "Folder Depth", each Text.End([Folder Path Full], [LenFolderPathFull]-lenRootFolderSearch+1)),
    #"helperList_ListFoldersDepth-Top2" = Table.AddColumn(fx_FolderDepth, "tmp_ListFoldersDepth", each List.Skip(
  List.FirstN(
    List.RemoveNulls(
      Text.Split([Folder Depth],"\")
    )
  ,3)
,1)),
    #"ListFoldersDepth-Top2" = Table.TransformColumns(#"helperList_ListFoldersDepth-Top2", 
{"tmp_ListFoldersDepth", each "\" & Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), "\") & "\"
, type text}),
    #"Select Needed Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"ListFoldersDepth-Top2",{"Name", "Folder Root", "Folder Depth", "tmp_ListFoldersDepth", "Content Type", "Kind", "Size", "Size(KB)", "Size(MB)", "Size(GB)"}),
    #"rename_FoldersParent(1-2)" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Select Needed Columns",{{"tmp_ListFoldersDepth", "Folders Parent (1-2)"}})
in
    #"rename_FoldersParent(1-2)"
```

Folder File Sizes_xlsx.png

[image]

Folder File Sizes_xlsx2.png

[image]

Comment: I WANTED to like this example, I really did. But you've left out way too many things. 

Like where /how to paste this query in:
Data ribbon > Get Data > From Other Sources > Blank Query
then paste it into the white space

How to add the parameter:
Power Query Editor > Home ribbon  > Manage Parameters> New Parameter

How to load the query to a worksheet:
Power Query Editor > Home ribbon > Close & Load > Close &Load

And probably the most important part - how to go from your Data Extract to the summarized Pivot table.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft offer a tool called `Disk Usage` which creates a CSV report.

> Du (disk usage) reports the disk space usage for the directory you specify. By default it recurses directories to show the total size of a directory and its subdirectories.

Here is how to use it:

> Usage: du [-c[t]] [-l  | -n | -v] [-u] [-q] 
>   Parameter   Description

Where the options are:

```
-c  Print output as CSV. Use -ct for tab delimiting.
-l  Specify subdirectory depth of information (default is all levels).
-n  Do not recurse.
-v  Show size (in KB) of intermediate directories.
-u  Count each instance of a hardlinked file.
-q  Quiet (no banner).
```

The CSV output is formatted as:

> Path, CurrentFileCount, CurrentFileSize, FileCount, DirectoryCount, DirectorySize

Here is the [current official link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/du).

Comment: "Microsoft offer a tool ..." yes they do, by the means of "sysinternals", who borrowed it from the Unix/Linux world -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_(Unix) -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Unix#1970s

Answer (score -1):

Just open power shell and do a `du -sh <directory>` no need to install 3rd party or sys-internals.  Within Power-shell you can run some simple Linux like commands like ls or du commands,  some of the switches won't work like `ls -alt` will error as powershell does not know what the -alt is...

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using? And are you sure you don't have Sysinternals installed? The "du" command does not appear to be built in on any systems I have access to. Some documentation link would be helpful too.

Comment: I'm on the latest fast insider channel of Windows 10 and there's absolutely no `du` command available

Answer (score -3):

The "dir" command provides file size, last modification date and time of the current directory. First try to move to the directory that you wish to look at the size of using the `cd` command, then use the `dir` command.

```
C:\>dir
```

Lists the file size, last modification date and time of all files and directories in the directory that you are currently in, in alphabetical order.

Comment: This is also a bad answer.  This will output the combined size of all the files in the current directory.  It will not however output the size of any directories in the current directory.  This simply doesn't do what the op is asking.