# Count files in a folder and subfolders from the command line

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

How do I count all files of a given type (eg. *.mp3) in a designated folder
(and optionally subfolders) from command line into a environment variable?

(no PowerShell please, just batch commands)

Comment: To the off-topic voters - questions about windows batch file programming are on-topic at [so]

Comment: [batch file - counting number of files in folder and storing in a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11004045/995714), [Batch file that counts the number of files in EVERY folder in a directory, and outputs results to a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38775955/995714)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check the size of a folder from the Windows command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/837016/how-can-i-check-the-size-of-a-folder-from-the-windows-command-line)

Comment: @phuclv the question is about file count not file size :-)

Comment: @KassMonk maybe the one that I used to close this was wrong, but there are other duplicates I already mentioned

Comment: Good point, sorry didnt see you were the same poster :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set filesCount=0 & for %f in (*) do @(set /a filesCount+=1 > nul)
```

Comment: Hmm. This solution gives 13 files for my test case. I wonder where the missing 4 files have gone?

Comment: Are those 4 files in a subfolder?

Comment: Ah. Yes, that's where they are hiding ;)

Comment: I think this is an elegant solution...  accepted!

Answer (score 7):

#### Count files in a folder and subfolders

Use the following command:

```
dir /b *.mp3 /s 2> nul | find "" /v /c > tmp && set /p count=<tmp && del tmp && echo %count%
```

The environment variable `%count%` will contain the number of files.

Note:

- Remove `/s` if you don't want to count files in subfolders.

---

#### Example (using *.txt)

Directory listing to show the 17 files:

```
F:\test>dir /b *.txt /s
F:\test\abc.txt
F:\test\blackwhite.txt
F:\test\cpu.txt
F:\test\interface.txt
F:\test\Lorem ipsum.txt
F:\test\right.txt
F:\test\rights.txt
F:\test\software.txt
F:\test\tabs.txt
F:\test\test.txt
F:\test\this is inside junction.txt
F:\test\unique.txt
F:\test\xyz.txt
F:\test\sub\abc.txt
F:\test\sub\xyz.txt
F:\test\sub with space\junction sub with space.txt
F:\test\sub with space\xyz.txt
```

Run the command:

```
F:\test>dir /b *.txt /s 2> nul | find "" /v /c > tmp && set /p count=<tmp && del tmp && echo %count%
17
```

---

#### Further reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [find](http://ss64.com/nt/find.html) - Search for a text string in a file & display all the lines where it is found.

Comment: You may consider adding `2> nul` to your `dir` command to omit the error message if no files are found.

Comment: @Steven Thx. Done

Answer (score 3):

Use a combination of `dir` and `find` to count the files.  Store the files into a variable via the `for` loop.  Redirect error output to `nul` to hide `File Not Found` error.

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('dir *.xlsx /s /b 2^> nul ^| find "" /v /c') do set VAR=%%i
echo %VAR%
```

See descriptions of parameters using `/?` for `dir`, `find`, and `for`.

Comment: Thanks... its a solution... but i wonder if we can simplify that... seems a bit of overload to pass all that info to a filter... even more if there are thousands of files in the folders

Comment: @ZEE The `for` loop is not needed - see my answer.

Comment: the `for` here is the superior solution to the creation of a temporary file in the other answer: 
the 'loop' is only executed once, for the single line of output of the command `dir *.xlsx /s /b 2^> nul ^| find "" /v /c`. But instead of writing that single line into a temp file, reading that file, and deleting the file, the `for`command directly reads the line.

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the party, but I just wanted to show support for [DavidPostill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill)

```
DIR [LEAVE BLANK FOR ALL FILES, *.mp3, *.*] /B /A-D /S 2>NUL | FIND "" /V /C > tmp
SET /P COUNT=<tmp
SET /A COUNT -= 1
DEL tmp
ECHO !COUNT!
```

This is my implementation; I prefer to split things up (since the command creates a file, it helps to decrement by one).

NOTE: The above INCLUDES files that are HIDDEN or are SYSTEM files.
To exclude HIDDEN and SYSTEM files replace [DIR...] with this instead

```
DIR [LEAVE BLANK FOR ALL FILES, *.mp3, *.*] /B /A-D-S-H /S 2>NUL | FIND "" /V /C > tmp
```

Also, it should be noted that the [dir ...] method is, at least an order of magnitude, more efficient than the [for ... VAR+=1] method.
My case was 510,000 files; using the DIR method, ~6 SECs; using the FOR method, ~4 MINs.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of robocopy's `/L` (list) option. Then you don't need any complicated for loops or pipes. It's very fast too.

```
robocopy c:\mydir c:\dummy /L /E *.mp3 *.txt
```

- `c:\mydir`: replace this with the path to the dir you want to search
- `c:\dummy`: you can leave this, it is just a dummy arg that is ignored since we are using `/L`
- `/L`: list only, will not copy/move anything.
- `/E`: include subdirs recursively. You can remove this if you don't want to search subdirs.
- If you don't want to print the list of files and dirs, you can add `/NFL` (No Files List) and/or `/NDL` (No Dirs List)

You will get a nice report like below. Just look at the `Total` column.

```
Source : c:\mydir

Files : *.mp3
        *.txt

--------------------------------------------------

{list of all the matching files}

--------------------------------------------------

            Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
 Dirs :         5         5         0         0         0         0
Files :        89        89         0         0         0         0
Bytes :   3.485 g   3.485 g         0         0         0         0
```