# Powershell to sum up disc space for specific file types

Tags: command-line, powershell

there is nice description to see how big is directory [here](https://superuser.com/questions/837016/how-can-i-check-the-size-of-a-folder-from-the-windows-command-line)

I would like to use Powershell (or CMD) to see how much space is consumed by for example *.bak files or files like Backup*.*

Comment: you can use `Get-ChildItem` for that, but it is slow. i suspect you will do better by using `robocopy` or start cmd.exe and run the `dir` command that it has. for instance, this >>> `robocopy c:\temp D:\Temp *.tmp /s /xj /nc /ndl /np /njh /l` <<< gives me 3 `*.tmp` files that take up 456 KB.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind running an external (non-shell) command, there is a dedicated Sysinternals utility: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/du

As well as, if you have WSL or Cygwin intsalled, you could run 'unix-native' `du -h` command.

Answer (score 0):

Robocopy is good idea:

```
robocopy C:\PDM_Archiv C:\Temp Bak*.* /S /L /NDL /NFL

/L  =>  log only, do not copy
/NDL => do not list directories
/NDF => do not list files
```