# How to get a particular line from a file into a batch variable?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have a batch file that gets it variable from a remote text file using a code something like this-

```
set /p var=< examplepath\example.txt
```

But the problem is that it will copy only the first line into the variable. Therefore I need to use one file for every variable. How to get all the data from only one file with variables taking their data from different lines?

For example I have this file `example.txt`,

> - data1
> - data2
> - data3

I want the `set /p` function to set ***var1***=***data1*** , ***var2***=***data2*** , ***var3***=***data3***

How do we do this?

Comment: You can't do it with `set /p`. See https://superuser.com/questions/1181376/windows-cmd-script-to-count-files-and-get-filenames/1181398#1181398 for one approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off 

cd /d "%~dp0" 
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

For /F tokens^=* %%i in ('type "example.txt"
')do set /a "_cnt+=1+0" && call set "_var!_cnt!=%%~i"

For /L %%L in (1 1 !_cnt!)do For /F tokens^=*usebackq %%i in (
`echo[!_var%%~L!`)do if not defined _var_ (set "_var_=_var%%L=!_var%%~L!"
     ) else set "_var_=!_var_!, _var%%~L=!_var%%~L!"
     
echo\!_var_!>example2.txt && set /p _var=<example2.txt

echo\!_var! && for /L %%L in (1 1 !_cnt!)do echo\!_var%%~L!

endlocal && goto :EOF
```

- Outputs:

```
_var1=data1, _var2=data2, _var3=data3         // -  From  echo\!_var!
data1                                         // |
data2                                         // |  From  For /L loop
data3                                         // |
```

---

**1.** Implement a counter inside a `For /F` loop taking line by line from your file:

```
For /F tokens^=* %%i in ('type "example.txt"
')do set /a "_cnt+=1+0" && ...
```

**2.** Each line will be saved isolated in the variable _var + counter

```
... && call set "_var!_cnt!=%%~i"
```

**3.** Implement a `For /L` loop starting at 1 and incrementing to the value defined in the counter == `! _cnt!`

```
For /L %%L in (1 1 !_cnt!)do ...
```

**4.** Concatenate the string *`_var`* with the variable in loop *`%%L`*, in order to recover the value of each line saved in *`_var%%L`* to use it in an additional `For /F` loop

```
... do For /F tokens^=*usebackq %%i in (
`echo[!_var%%~L!`)do
```

**5.** Use a conditional `if`, where the `_var_` variable has already been defined, define it in order to add more strings in the variable or, just define it with the value of the first line (*`var%%L == var1 == data1`*)

```
... do if not defined _var_ (set "_var_=_var%%L=!_var%%~L!"
     ) else set "_var_=!_var_!, _var%%~L=!_var%%~L!"
```

**6.** If for a reason you need this variable defined by `set /p`, echo the variable `_var` redirected to another file, and use it

```
echo\!_var_!>example2.txt && set /p _var=!<example2.txt
```

---

**Obs.: 1** Remember item **4.**: Concatenate the string *`_var`* with the variable in loop *`%%L`*, in order to recover the value of each line saved in *`_var%%L`* to use it in an additional `For /F` loop

```
echo\!_var! && for /L %%L in (1 1 !_cnt!)do echo\!_var%%~L!
```

**Ob.: 2** Both the variable *`_var_`* and *`_var`*, have the same content/strings/lines saved in them

```
echo\!_var! 
echo\!_var_!
```

---

---

- Some further reading:

  [√] **[If /?](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)**

  [√] **[Set /?](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html)**

  [√] **[Echo /?](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html)**

  [√] **[For /F /?](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)**

  [√] **[For /L /?](https://ss64.com/nt/for_l.html)**

  [√] **[Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)**

  [√] **[`Enable/DisableDelayedExpansion` | `Enable/DisableExtensions`](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)**

Answer (score 1):

3lines.txt

```
apple
bear
cat
```

test.bat

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set line=1
for /f "delims=" %%L in (3lines.txt) do (
    if "!line!"=="1" set var1=%%L
    if "!line!"=="2" set var2=%%L
    if "!line!"=="3" set var3=%%L
    set /a line+=1
    )

echo var1=%var1%
echo var2=%var2%
echo var3=%var3%
```

output:

```
var1=apple
var2=bear
var3=cat
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put the variable names in the text file, you can do the read in one line

3lines-2.txt

```
var1=Andy
var2=Bob
var3=Chris
```

test2.bat

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%L in (3lines-2.txt) do set %%L
echo var1=%var1%
echo var2=%var2%
echo var3=%var3%
```

output

```
var1=Andy
var2=Bob
var3=Chris
```